# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while Adding Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I want to update some information when a `save` button is clicked.

I got an error

> On : command.Parameters.Add("@doctorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
>   resident.Doctor.DoctorID; Saying: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Im guessing I need to create some kind of object?

**Button code:**

```
  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Resident hello = new Resident();
        hello.Doctor = new Doctor();
        Resident residentID;

        txtAdditionalInformation.Text = hello.addtionalInformation;
        txtForename.Text = hello.FirstName;
        txtSurname.Text = hello.Surname;
        txtTitle.Text = hello.Title;



        ResidentData.Update(hello);
    }
```

**update code (ResidentData Class):**

```
   public static void Update(Resident resident, SqlConnection connection,                  SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        SqlCommand command;

        sqlString.Append("UPDATE [Resident] SET ");
        sqlString.Append("title = @title, ");
        sqlString.Append("firstName = @firstName, ");
        sqlString.Append("surname = @surname, ");
        sqlString.Append("dateOfBirth = @dateOfBirth, ");
        sqlString.Append("photo = @photo, ");
        sqlString.Append("doctorID = @doctorID, ");
        sqlString.Append("roomID = @roomID, ");
        sqlString.Append("allergies = @allergies, ");
        sqlString.Append("additionalInformation = @additionalInformation ");
        sqlString.Append("WHERE residentID = @residentID ");
        command = new SqlCommand(sqlString.ToString(), connection);
        if ((transaction != null)) command.Transaction = transaction;

        command.Parameters.Add("@residentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.ResidentID;
        command.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Title);
        command.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.FirstName);
        command.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Surname);
        command.Parameters.Add("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.DateOfBirth);
        command.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image, 2147483647).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Photo);
        command.Parameters.Add("@doctorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Doctor.DoctorID;
        command.Parameters.Add("@roomID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Room.RoomID;
        command.Parameters.Add("@allergies", SqlDbType.NText).Value = resident.Allergies;
        command.Parameters.Add("@additionalInformation", SqlDbType.NText).Value = resident.addtionalInformation;
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (!(rowsAffected == 1))
        {
            throw new Exception("An error has occurred while updating Resident details.");
        }
    }
```

**Residence Class:*

```
 {
    public class Resident
    {

    private int residentID;
    private string title;
    private string firstName;
    private string surname;
    private string searchText;
    private System.DateTime dateOfBirth;
    private byte[] photo;
    private Room room;
    private Doctor doctor;
    private string nhs;
    private string residentBarcode;
    private string allergies;
    private string additionalInformation;

    public Resident()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public Resident(int newResidentID, string newTitle, string newFirstName, string newSurname, string newSearchText, System.DateTime newDateOfBirth, byte[] newPhoto, Room newRoom, Doctor newDoctor, string newNhs, string newResidentBarcode, string newAllergies, string newAdditionalInformation)
        : base()
    {
        residentID = newResidentID;
        title = newTitle;
        firstName = newFirstName;
        surname = newSurname;
        searchText = newSearchText;
        dateOfBirth = newDateOfBirth;
        photo = newPhoto;
        room= newRoom;
        doctor = newDoctor;
        nhs = newNhs;
        residentBarcode = newResidentBarcode;
        allergies = newAllergies;
        additionalInformation = newAdditionalInformation;
    }

    public int ResidentID
    {
        get { return residentID; }
        set { residentID = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname; }
        set { surname = value; }
    }

    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return searchText; }
        set { searchText = value; }
    }

    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return dateOfBirth; }
        set { dateOfBirth = value; }
    }

    public byte[] Photo
    {
        get { return photo; }
        set { photo = value; }
    }


    public Room Room
    {
        get { return room; }
        set { room = value; }
    }

    public Doctor Doctor
    {
        get { return doctor; }
        set { doctor = value; }
    }

    public string NHS
    {
        get { return nhs; }
        set { nhs = value; }
    }

    public string ResidentBarcode
    {
        get { return residentBarcode; }
        set { residentBarcode = value; }
    }

    public string Allergies
    {
        get { return allergies; }
        set { allergies = value; }
    }
    public string addtionalInformation{

        get { return additionalInformation; }
        set { additionalInformation = value; }

    } 


}
```

}

Comment: Show your resident class

Comment: My guess (and it's an educated one) is that `resident.Doctor` is null - you can't access `DoctorID` if `Doctor` is a null value... hence the null ref exception

Comment: Can you verify that in `resident.Doctor.DoctorID`, neither resident or Doctor is null?

Comment: I'm making the assumption that since it got to the aforementioned line, that the `resident.ResidentID` line executed successfully and therefore `resident` is not null - so logically it must be `Doctor` that's null

Comment: Off topic: but you can have that query in a string using the `@` string literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the way you've created your `Resident`:

```
Resident hello = new Resident();
ucMedicationCheckIn.SaveCheckedInMedication();
ResidentData.Update(hello);
ucMedicationCheckIn.HideDetails();
```

you probably haven't assigned it a doctor which is why it fails on this line:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@doctorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Doctor.DoctorID;
```

You need to initialize the `Doctor` type

Edit*

After seeing your `Resident` class I can see that you haven't initialized `Room` either.

You could provide a constructor to initialize these to default values:

```
public Resident()
{
    this.Doctor = new Doctor();
    this.Room = new Room();
    //etc...   
}
```

Though to do anything meaningful you will probably want to set these up with actual data before saving.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. The issue is that you're accessing the `Doctor/Room` members before initializing them. Providing a default constructor that sets these up will fix the immediate problem, however you still need to provide real data for your resident/doctor/room objects before you can save.

Comment: I have given it meaning full data please check the code I am getting the same error

Comment: No you haven't. You've created a **new** `Doctor`, you haven't set the `Doctor` up with data. You also haven't set up the `Room` which is also going to cause you issues judging by this line: `command.Parameters.Add("@roomID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Room.RoomID;`

Comment: How do I set an ID up with data? please see my question above where I set a method with data

Comment: You need to set the _object_ up with data, this includes the `ID` property. Unfortunately, it will be very difficult to tell _exactly_ how without seeing most of the code. You'll need to read through the source and figure that part out yourself or speak with the original developer.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `Doctor` and `Room` are not initialized anyhere:

```
Resident hello = new Resident();
hello.Doctor = new Doctor();
hello.Room = new Room();
```

but that update will probably fail as there is no meaningful data in `resident` and `rowsAffected` will return 0 probably.

Comment: @user2122032 Read this part: `but that update will probably fail as there is no meaningful data in resident and rowsAffected will return 0 probably.`. You need to create a `Resident` correctly.

Comment: How do I go about getting meaningful data?

Comment: You have to answer it yourself, see how your program works, how you want to achieve that. Or ask someone who wrote that code.